# Having problems using nested for loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop, ejs

I am having troubles figuring this one out. I want to compare the content from 2 arrays with each other. If they are === I want to run the if statement to occur otherwise the else statement. This works so far but the if and else occurs and not only 1 of them.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < match.interests.length; i++) { %>
    <% for (var j = 0; j < user.interests.length; j++) { %>
        <% if (match.interests[i] === user.interests[j]) { %>
            <li class="tag positive"><%= match.interests[i] %></li>
        <% } else {%>
            <li class="tag"><%= match.interests[i] %></li>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: What do you mean both occur and not only one? Are you saying both occur in the same iteration of the nested loop (That should be impossible)?

Comment: Lets say the Array a = ['Code', 'JS'] Array b = ['Code'] The result of this script right now is: Code Code JS and not Code JS @DylanHamilton

Comment: use break inside each if and else statements

Comment: You should try adding console.log in the line right before the if statement. Log i and j. That should help you figure out how many times each loop is running.

Comment: At some point you are comparing "Some value" to undefined because arrays are not of the same length.

Comment: Are all the interests you're comparing strings? Or can either of the array contain: numbers, objects, functions etc. as well? The reason I'm asking is that you only need one loop combined with `indexOf()` if it's only strings or numbers.

Comment: @Shilly Only 1 word strings. They are like tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your equality checks are fine, the issue comes because you are always logging something on the else statement.

```js
console.clear();

const match = {
  interests: [
    'Code',
    'JS'
  ],
};

const user = {
  interests: [
    'Code',
    'Apples',
    'Skiing'
  ],
};

const output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < match.interests.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < user.interests.length; j++) {
    console.log('loop')
    if (match.interests[i] === user.interests[j]) {
      console.log('MATCH');
      output.push(match.interests[i]);
    } else {
      console.log('DOESN\'T MATCH');
      output.push(match.interests[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

See the output of the following code, you need to decide what output you want and adjust your loops accordingly